# Triangle geometry: $BC^2+AC^2=n\cdot AB^2$.

Tags: geometry, reference-request, euclidean-geometry, triangles

I am looking for information regarding which triangles $ABC$ satisfy $BC^2+AC^2=n\cdot AB^2$ for $n=1,2,3,...$. I'm sure that work has already been done in this area since it is a fairly simple question to ask.

As an example, I have just proved that $n=2$ is true if and only if $\angle LAC =\angle ABM$ or $\angle ANC=\angle ALB$, where $L,M,N$ are midpoints of sides $BC,CA,AB$ respectively. (This means that in any triangle $ABC$ we have $\angle LAC=\angle ABM\iff \angle ANC=\angle ALB$, which is a problem by David Monk.)

What happens for $n=3,4,5,...$?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of numbers,
you want
$a^2+b^2 = nc^2$
where
$a+b > c, a+c > b, b+c > a$.

Assume
$a \ge b$.

If $a = b$
then
$2a^2 = nc^2$
or
$a = c\sqrt{n/2}$.
Since $c < 2a$,
$a < 2a\sqrt{n/2}$
or
$1 < 2n$
or
$n > 1/2$.
So every positive integer will work.
These correspond to isosceles triangles
that get narrower as $n$ gets larger.

If $a > b$,
once you have 
$a^2+b^2 = c^2$,
just multiply $a$ and $b$
by $\sqrt{n}$
to get
$a^2+b^2=nc^2$.

Don't know if this helps
or if this is what you want.